Does skipping Death also mean that other things triggered by Death's death can't happen, like Lilim's appearance?
After breaking the green Iron Maidens, it's possible to skip the water purifier and therefore Death, but am I locking myself out some monsters and their drops by doing so?
Because Lilim's drops are the best in the game until the Battle Arena. Even though I chose to not skip and am getting hit for 100+ by her.
